# What does the phrase "rolling down" mean in context?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I am not sure what "rolling down" means in the phrase "flight was rolling down the runway."  The word *roll* means "move somewhere by turning over and over or from side to side", which impresses me as "unsteady flying, dangerous" and I guess it might have been "spiralling down", which is safe.

What does "roll down" mean here?

> Duncan Clark’s **flight was rolling down the runway** in Paris in late October when President Emmanuel Macron announced a second national lockdown in France. The country had nearly 50,000 new Covid-19 infections that day. The United States had almost 100,000.

> Source:  NYTimes  [In a Topsy-Turvy Pandemic World, China Offers Its Version of Freedom](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/01/04/business/china-covid19-freedom.html)

Comment: It is the wheels which are rolling. Vehicles are hence said to roll.

Comment: Please see [**roll**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/roll) ***2** move or run on wheels. ‘The van was rolling along the lane.’* Or as they say "Let's roll!"